# How to generate permutations in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, permutation

In Oracle, I have a table of object types.

I would like to generate all the permutations on ITEM_PURPOSE_CODE.

The table looks something like this:

```
ITEM_PURPOSE_CODE  ITEM_CATEGORY_ID  ITEM_ID
==========================================
1                  101                50
2                  202                94
2                  202                95
```

What I would like then, is to generate a bunch of table types representing the permutations, for example:

```
ITEM_PURPOSE_CODE  ITEM_CATEGORY_ID  ITEM_ID
==========================================
1                  101                50
2                  202                94
```

and

```
ITEM_PURPOSE_CODE  ITEM_CATEGORY_ID  ITEM_ID
==========================================
1                  101                50
2                  202                95
```

Obviously this is a very simple case. There could be any number of item purpose codes (1 to n) and these codes could be repeated any number of times for differing item category IDs/item IDs.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I think is called combinations. In permutations order is important.

Comment: sounds like homework, but are you (or your prof) thinking of a cartesian product maybe?

Comment: @Eric . . . Can you describe why you are trying to do this?  The number of permutations grows very quickly and normally you would not want to store all of them in a database.

Comment: Hi Gordon, the reason for this is not to store the combinations in the database, but rather to allow a user to select from several different choices for each item purpose code. Rather than create these on the client side, I would prefer do it in Oracle. I was thinking of maybe joining the table to itself, but I am not an Oracle expert so I thought maybe there was a preferred approach. Thanks.

Comment: @GordonLinoff To be specific, the permutations are to be searched in the database, not stored there. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric . . . I still don't get it.  For a user interface, I could see wanting separate lists of values in eadch colum.  Are you just trying to get a random subset of rows?

Comment: In any case, sending exponentially growing data set over the network is the most ill-advised practice I can only imagine. And user searching through this huge list for an item of his choice will fill as baffled, as I fell right now, reading this. If you have N parameters of a product to choose from, why won't you give user N lists to click on to "construct" a product he wants?

Answer (score 3):

Please find the solution to generating combinations here. It was a nice variant on a previous problem we've had in our software for real estate development.

## Create and fill datamodel

First set up:

```
create table contents
( item_purpose_code number
, item_category_id  number
, item_id           number
)
/
begin
  insert into contents values (1, 101, 50);
  insert into contents values (2, 202, 94);
  insert into contents values (2, 202, 95);
  commit;
end;
/
```

## Assisting views

First I create some views. But ofcourse you can also inline them or use `with`.

```
--
-- Add to each row the consecutive number of the driver columns
-- (here only item_purpose_code) and for each different value
-- for the driver columns a consecutive number that restarts
-- when a new driver column value starts.
--
create or replace force view sequencedrows
as
select item_purpose_code
,      item_category_id
,      item_id
,      dense_rank() 
       over 
       ( order 
         by        item_purpose_code
       ) driver_seq 
,      row_number() 
       over 
       ( partition 
         by        item_purpose_code 
         order 
         by        item_category_id
         ,         item_id 
       ) 
       values_per_driver_seq
from   contents
/
--
-- Generate list of combinations.
-- 
create or replace force view combinations
as
select  sys_connect_by_path (driver_seq || '-' || values_per_driver_seq, '#') || '#' combination
from    sequencedrows
where   level = ( select max(driver_seq) from sequencedrows )
start 
with    driver_seq = 1
connect 
by  
nocycle driver_seq  = prior driver_seq + 1
/
```

With these, it becomes really simple since the combination is already contained in the field `combination` and the rows have been numbered:

```
select c.combination
,      s.item_purpose_code
,      s.item_category_id
,      s.item_id
from   combinations c
join   sequencedrows s
on     c.combination like '%#' || to_char(s.driver_seq) || '-' || to_char(s.values_per_driver_seq) || '#%'
order
by     c.combination
,      s.driver_seq
,      s.values_per_driver_seq
/
```

The results are:

```
#1-1#2-1#  1  101  50
#1-1#2-1#  2  202  94

#1-1#2-2#  1  101  50
#1-1#2-2#  2  202  95
```

## Performance

Depending on the data volume and indexes, the performance can be insufficient for interactive use. In our real estate development package we've however found that even with 50K rows generated performance is acceptable since Oracle 11g. Oracle 10g did a less optimal job on optimization.

When performance is unacceptable at your site, please list some key statistics or add a reproduction scenario.

Comment: hi @Eric was this answer helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When the answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?